# How to alias attribute if association exists in Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, alias

I would like to alias `name` attribute only if association `company` exists and if not then to return competitor `self.name`.

What would be the best way to do it in Rails 6?

I tried to use `alias_attribute` but it always aliased `name` to `company`.

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: competitors
#
#  id         :uuid             not null, primary key
#  name       :string
#  url        :string
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  company_id :uuid
#
# Indexes
#
#  index_competitors_on_company_id  (company_id) UNIQUE WHERE (company_id IS NOT NULL)
#
class Competitor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  alias_attribute :name, :company_name

  def company_name
    company.name
  end
end
```

Comment: I think you better just go with an instance method, don't think alias is meant for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a nice way to accomplish your goal with delegate

```
delegate :name, to: :company, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
```

The options like `:prefix => :fancy` and `:allow_nil => true` allow you to flavor your delegated method as you like.

The above example makes the method `company_name` available. That might be useful in general, as well in an accessor others have suggested.

```
def name
    company_name || super
end
```

More here https://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate

Answer (score 1):

How about just overriding name

```
  de name
      company.name || super
  end
```

I don't think alias is a good fit here

Comment: Could use `super` here. `company&.name || super`